# NSSocketPort with SSL

Tags: cocoa, ssl, nssocketport

I'm currently writing a server/client application, using an `NSSocketPort` hooked up to an `NSFileDescriptor` for event handling on the server side. This works perfectly fine, and the server and client have no trouble communicating.

However, I want to add SSL/TLS to secure the communications. With an `NSStream` I could set the `NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL` key to have the stream itself handle this encryption, but is there a similar feature for `NSSocketPort`, or would I have to implement this? I've searched through the documentation and have not found anything that would allow me to implement this SSL/TLS rather easily.

If I do have to implement it myself, what would be the simplest way of implementing this? A subclass of `NSSocketPort`, or something else? I'm relatively familiar with OpenSSL but any pointers (no pun intended) are of course appreciated on how to make this work decently with Cocoa.